# Gridworld- Can you add sound?

Tags: java, audio, gridworld

Just like the title. I'm wondering if it's possible to play a song in the background, and if so, how does the code go for that? I've googled endlessly to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So, don't 'google'.  Search suitable resources - like one of your books, or [this site](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=\[android\]+background+music).

Comment: I did that too and couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Clip class:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Clip.html

I've used this code for many projects, and it always works

```
try {
    // Open an audio input stream.
    URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("path/fileName");
    AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
    // Get a sound clip resource.
    clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    // Open audio clip and load samples from the audio input stream.
    clip.open(audioIn);
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
}
```